# Return type of net.forward()

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, object-detection, faster-rcnn

Hi I am working to detect the person by using faster rcnn model with tensorflow.
In the code I am referring it is mentioned

```py
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow(args["inferencegraph"],args["graphpbtxt"])
```

and after that:

```
detections = net.forward()
```

I am not getting what exactly detection is  and what contents it holds ?
For example is it a list or tuple and what are elements of it ?

Answer (score 3):

`net.forward()` gives `Numpy ndarray` as an output.

In your above example `detections = net.forward()` detections is an array output. if you calculate its shape then it will give 4 elements e.g. (1,1,200,7).

where 1,1 tell us number of images we are currently working on.

200 is the numbers of face detected which I have assumed above.

whereas 7 is vector of 7 values [Image number, Binary (0 or 1), confidence score (0 to 1), StartX, StartY, EndX, EndY].

```
for i in range(detections.shape[2]):    
    confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]
```

in this example loop will run over all the detected face and will return the confidence of each and every face that was detected.

Comment: can you pelase explain what the operator [0, 0, i, 2] does ? it is very confusing to see

Answer (score 2):

`cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow` takes your `Protobuf` file `.pb` and configuaration file of your model `.pbtxt` to load your saved model.

`net.forward()` - Runs a forward pass to compute the net output.

your detection i.e `net.forward()` will give `Numpy ndarray` as output which you can use it to plot box on the given input image.

You can consider the below example.

```
import cv2

# Load a model imported from Tensorflow
tensorflowNet = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow('frozen_inference_graph.pb', 'graph.pbtxt')

# Input image
img = cv2.imread('img.jpg')
rows, cols, channels = img.shape

# Use the given image as input, which needs to be blob(s).
tensorflowNet.setInput(cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, size=(300, 300), swapRB=True, crop=False))

# Runs a forward pass to compute the net output
networkOutput = tensorflowNet.forward()

# Loop on the outputs
for detection in networkOutput[0,0]:

    score = float(detection[2])
    if score > 0.2:

        left = detection[3] * cols
        top = detection[4] * rows
        right = detection[5] * cols
        bottom = detection[6] * rows

        #draw a red rectangle around detected objects
        cv2.rectangle(img, (int(left), int(top)), (int(right), int(bottom)), (0, 0, 255), thickness=2)

# Show the image with a rectagle surrounding the detected objects 
cv2.imshow('Image', img)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have considered `Inception-SSD v2` for weight file which can be downloaded from [here](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/ssd_inception_v2_coco_2017_11_17.tar.gz). 
And config file from this [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opencv/opencv_extra/master/testdata/dnn/ssd_inception_v2_coco_2017_11_17.pbtxt).

Comment: @Pratik - If the above answer solves your issue, please accept and upvote the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. So there is no backward pass, please? The I used to it is that we have a forward pass and then a backward pass.