# What does Mat[0,0,i,2] function do in Python with OpenCV

Tags: python, java, android, opencv

I am trying to understand this code and to convert it to Java

Code is from this tutorial, full code snippet shown below
https://pyimagesearch.com/2017/09/11/object-detection-with-deep-learning-and-opencv/

I want to convert the line
`confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]` to Java

`detections` is an OpenCV Mat class which is returned by `net.forward()`

First I need to understand what this means

Is this an ROI? Why is there an array of 4 values, what do they represent?

Next, how will this line of code look in Java?

Also this line is incredibly confusing to read
`box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])`

What does it mean and how can it be converted to Java?

```
# pass the blob through the network and obtain the detections and
# predictions
print("[INFO] computing object detections...")
net.setInput(blob)
detections = net.forward()

# loop over the detections
for i in np.arange(0, detections.shape[2]):
    # extract the confidence (i.e., probability) associated with the
    # prediction
    confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]
    # filter out weak detections by ensuring the `confidence` is
    # greater than the minimum confidence
    if confidence > args["confidence"]:
        # extract the index of the class label from the `detections`,
        # then compute the (x, y)-coordinates of the bounding box for
        # the object
        idx = int(detections[0, 0, i, 1])
        box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
        (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")
        # display the prediction
        label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(CLASSES[idx], confidence * 100)
        print("[INFO] {}".format(label))
        cv2.rectangle(image, (startX, startY), (endX, endY),
            COLORS[idx], 2)
        y = startY - 15 if startY - 15 > 15 else startY + 15
        cv2.putText(image, label, (startX, y),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, COLORS[idx], 2)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return type of net.forward()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59409692/return-type-of-net-forward)

Comment: No, I know the return type. I dont understand this syntax or even where to begin looking for its explanation `detections[0, 0, i, 2]` what are there 4 values in an array, what does it do? What does it return?

Comment: The dup is a bit of a tangent, but I think what you are really asking is what does `net.forward()` return. If you check the [Java documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/javadoc/org/opencv/dnn/Net.html#forward()), it's not very useful IMO, so perhaps the explanation in the dup will help you more.

Comment: Again, I know what net.forward() returns, Its a CV Mat, its in the question description. I need to understand what this returns `detections[0, 0, i, 2]`

Comment: The [answers to the dup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71163224/1270789) explain what they mean.

Comment: You may want to go through [NumPy Quickstart](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/quickstart.html) and [NumPy for Beginners](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/absolute_beginners.html)

Answer (score 0):

Convert from Python to Jave.

```
confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]
```

to:

```
double confidence = detections.get(i, 2)[0];
```